# target = _blank in PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

Noobie here. I need to insert target="_blank" into the following php code...any suggestions would be really appreciated :-)

```
<?php
                    echo wp_kses(
                        do_shortcode( "[cmo_footer_social][/cmo_footer_social]" ),
                        array(
                                'ul' => array (
                                        'class' => array()
                                ),
                                'i' => array (
                                        'class' => array()
                                ),
                                'li' => array ( ),
                                'a' => array (
                                        'class' => array(),
                                        'href' => array(),
                                )
                        )
                    );
                    ?>
```

Comment: paste the whole code

Comment: Complete guess never used WP but maybe...`'a' => array (
                                        'class' => array(),
                                        'href' => array(), 'target' => '_blank'`

Comment: where is this code being used?

Comment: do it using anology as @chris85 suggested

Comment: What do you get when echoing wp_kses()? An example may help. It seems clear enough how the element names and attributes are defined, but it's not clear what the attributes will contain when defined by an empty array. Anyway... try what @chris85 suggested.

Comment: As suggested in the answer @Tristan gave, add target to the array for 'a'. This will only form if the cmo_footer_social shortcode already has the target="_blank" in the HTML. This won't add to the HTML. If you want to add to the HTML, maybe use a preg_replace..

Answer (score 1):

`wp_kses()` filters content and keeps only allowable HTML elements. Depending on what the shortcode `[cmo_footer_social]` does, you may not need to filter the content at all (ie you may not need to use `wp_kses()`?).

The second parameter is allowed HTML tags, so just add target as suggested by @chris85, but without the value.

```
echo wp_kses(
    do_shortcode( "[cmo_footer_social][/cmo_footer_social]" ),
    array(
        'ul' => array (
                'class' => array()
        ),
        'i' => array (
                'class' => array()
        ),
        'li' => array ( ),
        'a' => array (
            'class' => array(),
            'href' => array(),
            'target' => array()
        )
    )
);
```